# Local images vs external images service in ReactJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, image

I am building a web app with a ReactJS for my front-end and a rails back-end API. I have to display only 4 images in total in the whole app; these 4 images are picked among a group of approximatively 50 images, and that group isn't going to grow much (maximum 10 more images per year). The 4 images are supposed to change every 3 to 7 days.

So I was thinking, **in terms of productivity, performance and price**, *what is the best way to handle my images between the following*:

- Create a local, static `img` folder in my React front-end, with all
  the images, and import them in my components.
- Use a Image upload/storage service like e.g. Cloudinary, Imgx, AWS S3... with my rails back-end to serve my images.

Or maybe there is even a better solution than these two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the nature of the software you're describing, I'd suggest you go with creating local and static images in your react front-end app.

The main reason for this is that:

1. You've mentioned that it's not going to be more than 10 images per year, so it's easy to handle it manually whenever you need to update it.
2. You won't be depending on a third-party in terms of storage (unlike using AWS S3, or any other provider, where you'll be unnecessarily depending on it)
3. The images will work independently of the backend API server, so even if there's some kind of failure in the backend, the platform will be even more robust, by not depending on the backend server to show these images.
4. This will also reduce the bandwidth used between server & client, every image request will be "hitting" the client app, which should have been automatically cached the JS, CSS and Images file, so it'd be automatically optimized for better scaling.